# Probability of choosing an ice cream flavor 7 times out of 30.

Tags: probability, statistics

An ice cream shop has 15 flavors. 30 customers randomly pick a flavor, what is the probability of a specific flavor being chosen 7 times.

Is it just the probability of the flavor picked P= 1/(15^30) seven times?

Comment: Actually just ${1\over 15}$ seven times if the question means "at least $7$ times". If it means "exactly seven times" then you need to multiply ${14\over 15}$ for the remaining people.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If yes, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Look up the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  Assuming you mean exactly seven times, you need to choose $7$ customers to be the ones that choose that flavor and the other $23$ have to choose something else.  It is ${30 \choose 7}\left(\frac 1{15}\right)^7\cdot \left(\frac {14}{15}\right)^{23}$.  This assumes unrealistically that all the flavors are chosen with equal probability and that one customer's choice does not influence the next.

Comment: I think the answer should be $\binom{30}{7}\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)^7\left(\frac{14}{15}\right)^{23}$

Comment: @HarisGusic:  right you are.  A copy/paste error.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you mean exactly 7 times.

The total number of ways the customers can pick their ice cream is $15^{30}$, since each "choosing" is a 30-variation of the set of flavours.

Now we will determine the number of ways exactly 7 customers chose a specific flavour.

First, we must choose 7 customers who will pick that flavour. This can be done in $\binom{30}{7}$ ways. The remaining 23 customers can pick any of the remaining 14 flavours, which can be done in $14^{23}$ ways. Using the multiplication principle we get that the number of ways that exactly 7 customers choose a specific flavor is $\binom{30}{7}14^{23}$.

Therefore, the probability is $\binom{30}{7}\frac{14^{23}}{15^{30}}$.

However, all of this assumes that the customers pick their ice cream independently from each other.